# Astronomical measurements and data

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, universe, data

For the sub-nuclear physics there is a database of the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/), I was wondering if there was a similar on-line collection for astrophysics, such as energy absorption and emission spectra for different sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a wide variety of databases covering all sorts of data, and I won't try and list them all here (but I'll list some of the largest ones). There isn't anything as clear-cut as the Particle Data Group because astronomy deals with complex systems (as opposed to the more fundamental particles in sub-nuclear), and there's no saying that the spectrum of source XX won't change tomorrow. Some sources are more transient than others, and it's often possible to estimate a timescale for transience, but there's always the possibility of some unknown effect coming into play or some unresolved source entering the region and wreaking havoc on the status quo.

I think the closest thing to what you're asking about would be [virtual observatories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_observatory). There are a number of organizations/countries with VO projects, here are a few:

- [USVAO](http://www.usvao.org/) (also a [public outreach site](http://www.virtualobservatory.org/))
- [SkyView](http://skyview.gsfc.nasa.gov/)
- [EuroVO](http://www.euro-vo.org/)
- [CVO](http://www.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/cvo/)

There are also a few source catalogs maintained by the [Centre de Données de Strasbourg](http://cds.u-strasbg.fr/) (Simbad, Vizier, Aladin) which are quite extensive, and another by NASA called [NED](http://nedwww.ipac.caltech.edu/).

Some of the largest collections of survey data are [SDSS](http://www.sdss.org/) (>1/4 of the sky in 5 bands from about the near-IR to the near-UV with hundreds of millions of objects catalogued, and millions of spectra), [2MASS](http://www.ipac.caltech.edu/2mass/) (all-sky survey in the near-IR), [MAST](http://archive.stsci.edu/) (compendium of catalogs from the Space Telescope Science Institute). The data from the [Planck](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Planck) (IR/radio, all sky), [Fermi](http://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/) (gamma ray, all sky) and [Chandra](http://chandra.harvard.edu/) (x-ray) satellites are (or will be) publicly archived, and many other archives of data from particular telescopes exist as well.

If you're interested in a particular source (or type of source), or a particular waveband, I might be able to recommend a database.